# Scale CCSprite to exact size

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

What is the best technique to scale a sprite to an exact size. The scale property is a multiplier, but if you want a sprite to be exactly X pixels wide, is there a simple technique? Or, would it require simply using the desired size and the sprites actual `contentsize` to calculate the necessary `scale` operation?

Comment: Honestly, i have always proceeded as per your suggestion (compute scaleX and scaleY), not looking for another answer. I'll just add this question as a favorite, see what the scientists dredge up as an answer.

Comment: Calculating the scale multiplier using new size and current size is the only way to go (or you can always create a method for that) because internally, cocos2d simply sends the `scaleX` and `scaleY` values to `glScalef` openGL function when it's time to draw the sprite.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this works:

```
-(void)resizeSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite toWidth:(float)width toHeight:(float)height {
    sprite.scaleX = width / sprite.contentSize.width;
    sprite.scaleY = height / sprite.contentSize.height;
}
```

Put it in your game, and use like this:

```
[self resizeSprite:mySprite toWidth:350 toHeight:400];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two properties : scaleX and scaleY .
for example, use in a HP Bar.

hpBarSprite.scaleX = hpCurrent / hpMax ;

Comment: For a bar, it should be `((1.0 / max) * current)` since 1.0 is 100%.